# Mac Wireless Keyboard - random key presses, possessed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, bluetooth

As a tech guy, I am really baffled by what's going on with my keyboard. All search results point to the keyboard shortcut settings, but I have been hammering the "Set to Default" button in there, to no effect.

My keyboard is the Apple Wireless Keyboard, bluetooth with 2x AA batteries.
It has just turned 2 years old.

It all started with the `ESC` key that simply stopped working about a month ago. This was a few weeks before my warranty would expire, so I contacted the retailer, but they didn't want to provide any support, only suggesting I deliver both my keyboard AND MacBook to their repair center.

Maybe I would have done that, if I wasn't on the other side of the world. Now the warranty has expired, and problems are getting worse.

Could it be wireless interference? Some internal short circuit? Let me know if you know of anything similar.

**What I have tried**

- Resetting Keyboard Shortcuts.
- Toggling every Accessibility feature on and off again.
- Changing Input Sources (keyboard layout).
- Replacing batteries in the keyboard with a fresh pair of Duracells.
- Remove pairing from MacBook and force re-pair.
- Rename keyboard.
- Boot my MacBook from a Linux USB. Keyboard is acting the same.

**Other info**

- The issue has persisted through the upgrade to macOS High Sierra, but wasn't as bad before.
- I do have a custom keyboard layout (made with Ukelele), and the issues started some time *after* that. However, I have tried switching and removing my custom keyboard layout (so none other than the default layout is enabled), makes no difference.
- There seems to be **nothing** wrong with the built-in keyboard, it acts completely normal while the wireless keyboard is freaking out.
- The only other bluetooth device I am using simultaneously is the Apple Magic Mouse - no issues there.
- I have never spilled anything in the keyboard, or done it any harm - other than typing a lot, and hard.

**Other symptoms**

Typing the `@` symbol (on my EU keyboard that's `Alt` + `'`) suddenly stopped working. Nothing happened, but without the `Alt` modifier, the `'` key worked fine. And the `Alt` modifier was working fine with other keys as well. Sometimes the *Audio Preferences* randomly open up...

Then one day I was typing my password, and not being able to log in. Seems my `P` has magically started turning Caps Lock on and off.

Lately the keyboard's `ESC` key is working again, and it feels like the keyboard is either working 100% or acting crazy 100%. Meaning, in the beginning of this post my `S` key would append `-` and `SPACE` a `z` when typing, and seconds later I can type a full sentence with no interference.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm experiencing the exact same problems, with a Logitech K780 keyboard connected via BT. I'm still running MacOS Mojave.

Answer (score 3):

Since your built-in keyboard seems to work fine, I'd try to reset both the macOS Bluetooth Device List and Bluetooth Controller.

**IMPORTANT:** This will reset **all** connected Bluetooth devices, including your Apple Magic Mouse, so your wireless keyboard and mouse will need to be reconnected.

Before commencing, you will need to have the Bluetooth icon showing in the menu bar. If it is not there, open System Preferences > Bluetooth and enable the option *Show Bluetooth in Menu Bar*.

**Resetting the macOS Bluetooth Device List and Bluetooth Controller**

Follow these steps:

1. Hold down both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys and at the same time click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. Once the menu is showing, release the keys.
2. From the Bluetooth menu, choose Debug > Remove All Devices
3. Hold down both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys again and at the same time click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar.
4. From the Bluetooth menu,  choose Debug > Reset the Bluetooth Module
5. Restart your Mac
6. Setup your keyboard again
7. Setup your Magic Mouse again

Let us know whether this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I didn't know about the Debug menu. Following your steps seems to have helped, but I will give it a few days to be sure. Otherwise the Bluetooth debug menu also had a "Factory reset Apple devices" I could try.

Comment: The devil has returned. It started with sporadic disconnects/reconnects, that intensified in frequency, until it stopped disconnecting and now adds random letters to what I'm writing instead... I have just tried the device factory reset option from Bluetooth menu, but that didn't help for a second.